# Smartsheet extract sheet ranges for reuse in another sheet - node.js

Tags: node.js, smartsheet-api

Not sure if this is possible...

I use a Smartsheet workspace as a template.  One of the sheets needs to be updated monthly (based on an external body changing requirements).  They kindly provide an xml file for the update.  To do that I wipe the rows off the sheet and then using the XML and node.js rebuild the sheet. That's working like a charm :-)

This master sheet contains ranges for calculations on a different summary sheet.  By this I mean that the calculation sheet refers to the master sheet in a formula such as:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS({master sheet! Range 1}, $Primary@row, {master sheet! Range 2}, B$2), COUNTIFS({master sheet! Range 1}, $Primary@row, {master sheet! Range 2}, B$3), COUNTIFS({master sheet! Range 1}, $Primary@row, {master sheet! Range 2}, B$4), COUNTIFS({master sheet! Range 1}, $Primary@row, {master sheet! Range 2}, B$5), COUNTIFS({master sheet! Range 1}, $Primary@row, {master sheet! Range 2}, B$6))
```

As you can see in this single formula there are references to Range 1 and Range 2.  These are system generated names (which I know I can change).

The issue is when I wipe the rows I also wipe the ranges. :-(

Is it possible to read the ranges before I wipe the sheet, and then somehow import them back into the sheet once it's updated?

Advice appreciated.

Bowow99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know the `id` of the *summary sheet* (i.e., the sheet that contains formulas referencing ranges in the sheet you're wiping/updating periodically)?

If so, it seems like you could run the [List Cross-sheet References](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#list-cross-sheet-references) operation on the *summary sheet* -- to get the list of all cross-sheet references that the sheet uses.

Then after you've wiped data from the other sheet and added new data to it, you could run the [Create Cross-sheet Reference](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?javascript#create-cross-sheet-references) operation on the *summary sheet* to create any references to the sheet where you wiped/updated data exactly as they existed before (i.e., using the data that was returned in the **List Cross-sheet References** response).

***Note:*** If there are any other sheets, besides the *summary sheet* that use cross-sheet references to reference ranges in the sheet where you're wiping/recreating data, then you'd need to do this same process for each of those sheets as well.

Comment: Sounds like a plan.  I will give it a go and let you know what happens :-)  Thanks

Comment: Got it working nicely.  Thanks for the guidance :-)

Comment: Excellent -- happy to hear that. Thanks for the update!